# php mysql download link

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, download

On this page, a user picks some options from drop downs and receives a list of files available for download.  Download hyperlink next to each record.  Currently the download hyperlink downloads a file with the correct FILE NAME as it exists in the database, but the file CONTENTS are incorrect. More specifically, it seems like a header is not being sent correctly: The contents of the file is the html markup from newpub_profile.php

This is the most current code:

newpub_profile.php

```
       $q = "SELECT upload_id, title, genre, length, created
        FROM upload
        WHERE genre = '$genre' AND length = '$length'
        ORDER BY created DESC, title DESC";


    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query

    if($r)
    {
        // If it ran okay, display the records
        echo '<table align="center"
            cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"
            width="75%">
           <tr><td align="left"><b>Title</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Genre</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Pages</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Submitted</b></td>
           <td align="left"><b>Download</b></td>';

        // Fetch and print all the records:

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
            $row['title'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . $row['genre'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . $row['length'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . $row['created'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            //. $row['views'] . '</td><td align="left">'
            . "<a href='newpub_profile.php?id={$row['upload_id']}'>Download</a></td>" . '</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>'; // Close the table

        mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources
    }
    else // If it did not run okay
    {
        // Public Message:

        echo '<p class="error">Your submissions could not be retrieved.  We
            apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';

        // Debugging message:

        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

    } // End of if ($r) IF.



}

//END DOWNLOAD HANDLER ******************************************************


    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection

?>
                    <?php

                    // Make sure an ID was passed DOWNLOAD HANDLER *******
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['id']); var_dump($id);


    require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db



        // Fetch the file information
        $downloadq = "
            SELECT `file_type`, `size`, `title`, 'content', 'upload_id'
            FROM `upload`
            WHERE `upload_id` =".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $downloadq); // Run the query


        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                //var_dump($row);

                // Print headers
                header("Content-Type: ". $row['type']);
                header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
               header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['title']);


                // Print data
                echo stripslashes($row['content']);
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No such ID.';
            }

            // Free the mysqli resources
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbc->error}</pre>";
        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }

                    ?>
```

newupload_sql.php

```
        if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) //check membership level here*******************************************
{
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //$membercheck = "SELECT membership, uploaded
                   // FROM user
                   // WHERE user_id =". $_SESSION['user_id'];  //gets membership level and upload count

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 2621440)
        die("File larger than 2.5MB");

       $mimeTypes = array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
'application/msword');

    if (in_array($_FILES['userfile']['type'], $mimeTypes))
      {
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$oid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$views = 0;


$fp      = fopen($fileName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($fileName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

//if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
//{
  //  $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
//}

$query = "INSERT INTO upload (title, file_type, size, content, length, genre, created, views, description, owner_id) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileType','$fileSize', '$content', '$length', '$genre', NOW(), '$views', '$description', '$oid')";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query); //Run the query. or die('Error, query failed');

if($r)
{

        require_once ('login_functions.php');
        $url = absolute_url ('newupload_thanks.php');
        header("Location: $url");
        exit();
}

            else //if it didnt run ok...
            {
                //Public message:
                echo '<h1>System Error</h1>
                <p class="error">You could not upload due to a system
                error.  We apologize.</p>';

                //debugging message:

                echo'<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $r .
                '</p>';

            } // End of ($r) IF. // File's OK
    }

}
  else
    {
        die("Wrong tile type: Use .doc, .docx or ONLY");

    }



}mysqli_close($dbc); //Close the database connection.
?>
```

Comment: clicking the download link in my table results in downloading page itself.  example: the download table occurs in download.php, clicking "download" should download the file in my database, but instead its downloading download.php

Comment: " the hyperlink with value $upload_id " ? There is no $upload_id in your code anywhere. Is it possible you have a typo or misnamed variable or something? Anyway, when you run this, what do you get?

Comment: As @itachi said, remove all the `@`. Those are suppressing errors. Removing them will probably give you the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is downloading the page itself? From the looks of it your issue is that you are not building the header correctly. Your SQL query and var_dump indicates that you are fetching a `title` but you use `name` for filename of the download offer (actually making the code send a header with empty filename.

I'd suggest you verify that your code uses the actual column name. i.e.:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['title']);
```

Comment: made the change from  $row['name'] to $row['title'] - Now I can download a file with the correct file name, in this instance its "css_file.doc".  When I open the file it contains the html of newpub_profile.php

Comment: with the code you have pasted it would appear as if you are unconditionally creating the HTML table and then offering a download. If you are using separate files, mayve you could edit your question to show what the code is on each file

Comment: thanks but it is still not clear which file is which. I'd suggest you add the code for the file that generates the output of the page the user is in to click on the download link and the code of the page that  they land on (the one that you use for upload appears to be completely irrelevant here)

Comment: the very top of the question is the table echo.  "DOWNLOAD" is displayed for each record in the table as a hyperlink.  The link is then clicked.  I believe I have posted everything I can possibly share aside from HTML that I dont believe is relevant.  What is happening here is a person logs in and goes to their profile, this specific type of person selects options from a few checkboxes and the results are returned with a download link corresponding to each record.  the download link id is linked to $upload_id.  Currently clicking download results in a header being sent incorrectly I think

Comment: it still isn't clear to me what of all the code you posted belongs to `newpub_profile.php`. And if there are several chunks that belong to it, it would be great to show the whole file as your problem appears to be that the file itself is acting up so all its code would appear to be relevant

Comment: Understood, I edited the question to be a little easier to understand.

Comment: The downloaded file will have everything that it is output by the php file. From the looks of the code you have posted, you output the HTML unconditionally before the download headers. It doesn't make sense that you are indeed offered a download if that is the case but that's what we can see from the code you have posted

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I need to isolate the download ISSET in its own php file and do an include statement?

Comment: not necessarily, but it may be a good idea for the downloading to be on its own file. After all - from the looks of it - you are not sharing any code between that and the code above it

Answer (score 1):

There is no row['name'] do you mean row['title']

Comment: That change now allows me to download the correct file name, but incorrect file contents. File contents are the html for newpub_profile.php

Answer (score 1):

You have these

```
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
```

You have to rename/move $tmpName to $filename

**EDITED**

Check this 
[move_uploaded_file()](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

or change $fileName with $tmpName in the following block

```
$fp      = fopen($fileName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($fileName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Originally I had fopen($tmpName, 'r'); ...  then switched to $fileName.  Is it possible to take an upload directly from POST and put it in mysql or must I use move_uploaded_file() to move the upload to a temporary directory, insert to database, and delete the directory

Comment: I haven't try it before. I don't think I would ever put a file into DB. I would suggest create a unique filename and store it in a folder then store the link into the DB. This way is more efficient.